# Discretization of PDE

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I have encountered an interesting PDE, where $f\in C^1_0(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
\partial_x u(x, t) + \partial_t u(x, t) = -f+u(x, t)\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(s)\chi_{\lbrace y: u(y, t) \geq f(y) \rbrace}(s)~\mathrm{d}s, \quad x, t \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Solving this analytically is rather hard, so I just tried to discretize it.

I calculated $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} u(y+t, t)$ for fixed $y$ which gives me an ugly ODE with some delay...

Does anyone have a better idea on how to solve this on a computer? Any domain $[a, b] \times [c, d]$ would be fine for me.

Comment: At a glance it seems like it might be useful to figure out the ODE satisfied by the integral. But this might be quite hard if $u$ is not monotone in time for fixed space.

Comment: True, true. Aleady tried this. Discretizationof the integral would be okay, too, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side is an advection operator, so I guess a simple explicit upwind scheme would work. It also needs some boundary condition at $x = a$ and initial conditions at $t = t_0$.

$$
\frac{u^n_j - u^n_{j-1}}{\Delta x} + 
\frac{u^{n+1}_j - u^n_j}{\Delta t} =
-f_j + u^n_j I^n, \quad j = 1, \dots, M, \quad n = 0, \dots, N-1\\
u^0_j = u_0(x_j)\\
u^{n+1}_0 = b(t_{n+1})
$$

Let's approximate the integral with a trapezoidal rule:
$$
I^n = \Delta x\sum_{j=1}^M \frac{f^n_{j-1} [u^n_{j-1} > f_{j-1}] + f^n_j [u^n_j > f_j]}{2}
$$

For stability you need $C = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} < 1$ (CFL condition) and $\Delta t < -\frac{2}{I^n}$ (if $I_n$ becomes negative)

Here's a quick and dirty implementation of the scheme in Python https://gist.github.com/uranix/82e88262135088d8a66e9f6a8c684ea5

Comment: Wow, thank you. This is phenomenal. But what exactly does $[u_{j-1}^n > f_{j-1}]$ mean? Just a simple yes no condition?

Comment: @Meowdog It's an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket, another notation for indicator function (besides $\chi$).

Comment: Sorry, another quick question: In the $I^n$ formula, why is it $u_{j-1}^n[u_{j-1}^n>f_{j-1}]$ instead of $f^n_{j-1}[u_{j-1}^n>f_{j-1}]$

Comment: Oops, that was my error. Will fix now. The program was correct already

Comment: Yup, saw it afterwards, but thanks.